# Create a Single from a SingleEmitter

Tags: android, rx-java2

I have a link to a `SingleEmitter` that was saved during `Single.create()` execution and is used later to emit an event.

Now I want to create another `Single` that will be subscribed from a different place but use the same underlying `SingleEmitter`.

In other words, I want to have a method that gets `SingleEmitter<MyObject>` as an argument and returns `Single<MyObject>.`

Is it possible to do it in RxJava 2?

Here is an example:

```
  SparseArray<SingleEmitter<MyObject>> activityResultListeners = new SparseArray<>();

  // Somewhere in the code
  public Single<MyObject> doSmth() {
    return Single.create(observableEmitter -> {
      resultListeners.put(requestId, observableEmitter);
    });
  }

  // Somewhere in another place
  public void onResult(int requestId) {
     activityResultListeners.remove(requestCode);
  }

  // And now we want to have
  public Single<MyObject> subscribeToExistingItem(){
     // return Single.fromWhat?
  }
```

Comment: Use SingleSubject instead.

Comment: paste the code snippet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not leak the `SingleEmitter` out of the `Single.create()` but use `SingleSubject` to talk to multiple observers:

```
private SingleSubject<MyObject> subject = SingleSubject.create();

subject.subscribe(success -> { }, error -> { });
subject.subscribe(success -> { }, error -> { });

subject.onSuccess(/* notify the two current SingleObservers */);

// will receive the notification too
subject.subscribe(success -> { }, error -> { });
```

Comment: Thank you. What if I wanted to work only with one observer? Should I still use SingleSubject?
And about not leaking SingleEmitter outside the create method - is it just because it was designed to work like this or there are some additional issues that may emerge in case of leaking it?

Comment: Even if you have one `SingleObserver` and having an external source of the terminal signal, you should still use `SingleSubject`. If devs see `create()` in the code, they will assume a localized per consumer activity. Thus, if the emitter is leaked and later on there will be multiple observers, they will overwrite each other's emitter and suddenly only one observer will receive the events and the other not.